# Converting barycentric coordinates to polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

One can find many references on converting barycentric coordinates to cartesian coordinates, but I can't find anything on barycentric to polar. So right now, I'm doing barycentric to cartesian followed by cartesian to polar. Not very efficient...

If my barycentric reference is an equilateral triangle with the vertices radius at 1 and azimuth at pi/3 (60°), pi (180°) and 5pi/3 (300°), how can I find the polar coordinates of a point defined by barycentric coordinates?

Comment: I honestly think going from barycentric to cartesian to polar coordinates is the best way to go.
Maybe if you have $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ as barycentric coordinates then you get an angle of $\alpha{\pi\over 3}+\beta {\pi}+\gamma {\pi\over 5}$ ? I'm not really sure about this.